# Preencher uma combobox jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Veja não é popular uma combo, isso eu fazer. A combo está populada, aí preciso pegar o id e mostrar na combo o text referente àquele ID. O ID eu tenho na minha table, só falta mostrar o text na combo. Minha jquery está assim:

```
function CarregaDados(ajaxParameter) {
    $.ajax({

        url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ _nivel: ajaxParameter }),
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                $('#txtNome').val(itemData.NM_Usuario);
                $('#txtUsuarioRede').val(itemData.Usuario1);
                $('#txtEmail').val(itemData.Email);
                //$('#cbxNivelAcesso').val();
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    })
}
```

cbxNivelAcesso é a minha combo. Está comentada, porque testei de várias formas e nada.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem o que quer. Mas vou te mostrar duas opções, tanto pegando o valor do texto selecionado da combo, ou passando o value do option para recuperar o texto.

```
$("#cbxNivelAcesso").children("option").filter(":selected").text();
```

ou passando o value

```
$("#cbxNivelAcesso option[value='2']").text()
```

Comment: Deixa-me explicar melhor. Na minha combo tem três registros, com ID's: 1, 2 e 3. Quando o ID = 3, o texto deve a ser mostrado é: AÇÃO. Se o ID = 2 o text a ser mostrado é: Consulta e se for ID = 1 o texto é: ADMINISTRAÃO. É isso que eu não consigo.

Comment: Esse texto deve ser mostrado aonde ? Copia sua combo e cola ela aqui por favor.

Comment: Na combobox. Assim. Existe uma table e quando o usuário der um double click, existe quatro campos que serão preenchidos para serem editados e um desses campos é a combobox

Comment: Acho que entendi, a pessoa seleciona um valor e você quer que o mesmo dinamicamente seja carregado na combo ?

Comment: Se for isso mesmo, tenta deixar a combo selecionada assim 

$("#cbxNivelAcesso option[value='3']").attr('selected','selected');

Ai no value tu pode trocar a constante por uma variável.

Comment: Vinicius, isso resolve, agora não consigo carregar o IDNivel, porque ele é uma Foreign Key. Mas vou fechar esse tópico e tentar resolver a outra questão. Se não conseguir, abro outro post.

Comment: Responde Vinicius para eu fechar com a sua resposta.

Comment: Isso resolveu: $('#cbxNivelAcesso option[value=' + itemData.IDNivel_Acesso + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: Desculpa amigo, estava na faculdade. Bacana demais, se tiver mais alguma coisa que eu possa lhe ajudar, pode mandar aí.. Mas se não, por favor finaliza o post com um joinha. Abraço ;)

Comment: Como eu coloco um joinha na minha resposta ou comentário para fechar o post?

Comment: No meu post você clica na setinha para cima e logo abaixo dela vai ter uma opção de aceitar. :D